# Flexible div positioning

Tags: css, html, position

I have several divs on a page that all have the same width but different heights. They are all in one div, the `#note1PreviewDiv`. They all share the class `.note`, which has the following css code (among other):

```
.note{
    width: 160px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #e3f0ff;
    float: left;
}
```

I thought with `float: left;` they would all automatically align so that they are well aligned among each other.

Here's a preview of what it looks like:

[Current state http://posti.sh/img/ist.png](http://posti.sh/img/ist.png)

And here's what the positioning should be like:

[Desired state http://posti.sh/img/soll.png](http://posti.sh/img/soll.png)

I think you get the idea. Somehow it seems to me the height of the leftmost div pushes the other divs in the second row to the right - but that's only guessing.

Thanks for your help!

Charles

Comment: It is with CSS3! See my answer. Browser support is not ideal though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this easily with CSS only.

CSS3 has a new feature called column layout, but browser support is not great. IE9 and below don't support it.

See http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/ and the last example for CSS3 solution.

Have a look at these js / jQuery options for easier implementation and browser support:

- [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [isotope](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGgQFjAB&url=http://isotope.metafizzy.co/&ei=s70TUNrXINSfiQemo4DYBg&usg=AFQjCNHzbG2dSuid3yQGg-80of_sFMnasw)
- [vanilla masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/index.html) which doesn't need jQuery.
- [wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)

Comment: That did it for me! I chose the masonry jQuery solution and it works like a charm. The one condition though is that the elements either have a fixed height or are displayed from the beginning. So I assigned fixed heights.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of lay out you want is really difficult (not possible?) without going for a column based approach and adding additional block elements to represent each column. This obviously won't work with a flexible number of columns if you want a dynamic layout based on screen size.

That said, you could always use JavaScript to dynamically place elements into columns, and get it to match the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Is the height of the parent container given a fixed value? If it is, try setting the height of the parent container to auto, and the overlow propery to hidden.